# C++98 alternative to std::stoul?

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm having trouble here with this code:

```
unsigned long value = stoul ( s, NULL, 11 );
```

that gives me this error with c++ 98

```
error: 'stoul' was not declared in this scope
```

It works on C++11, but I need this on C++98.

Comment: Why on earth do you pass `s.c_str()` to `stoul`, which accepts `std::string` if type of `s` is `std::string`?

Comment: You can try `strtoul`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Im sorry, got it edited now

Comment: What is type of `s`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`strtoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) from `cstdlib`:

```
unsigned long value = strtoul (s.c_str(), NULL, 11);
```

Some differences:

1. The second argument of `std::stoul` is a `size_t *` which will be set to  the position of the first character after the converted number, while the second argument of `strtoul` is of type `char **` and points to the first character after the converted number.
2. If no conversion happens, `std::stoul` throw a [`invalid_argument`](http://www.cplusplus.com/invalid_argument) exception while `strtoul` does not (you must check the value of the second argument). Typically, if  you want to check for error:

```
char *ptr;
unsigned long value = strtoul (s.c_str(), &ptr, 11);
if (s.c_str() == ptr) {
    // error
}
```

3. If the converted value is out of range for an `unsigned long`, `std::stoul` throws a [`out_of_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/out_of_range) exception while `strtoul` return `ULONG_MAX` and set `errno` to `ERANGE`.

---

Here is *custom* version of [`std::stoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoul/) that should behave like the standard one and summarizes the difference between `std::stoul` and `strtoul`:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <cerrno>

unsigned long my_stoul (std::string const& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10) {
    char *endp;
    unsigned long value = strtoul(str.c_str(), &endp, base);
    if (endp == str.c_str()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("my_stoul");
    }
    if (value == ULONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE) {
        throw std::out_of_range("my_stoul");
    }
    if (idx) {
        *idx = endp - str.c_str();
    }
    return value;
}
```